# What is the Joint probability?

Tags: probability

| X | W |
| --- | --- |
| 0.2 | W1 |
| 0.3 | W1 |
| 0.6 | W2 |
| 0.4 | W2 |
| 0.6 | W1 |
| 0.2 | W1 |
| 0.8 | W2 |
| 0.5 | W1 |
| 0.2 | W1 |
| 0.6 | W2 |

I have this (random) table of pairs.

Is the joint probability of **0.2 AND W1** = 18/100 = 0.18 ?

Or 3/10 = 0.3 ?

The answer key I have says 0.3 but I am confused as joint probability, as I understand, means multiplying P(A) with P(B) = P(0.2) * P(W1) = 3/10 * 6/10 = 18/100 = 0.18

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

The joint probability is indeed 0.3

Your computation with the multiplicative formula gives the joint probability **if the two variables are independent**.

So clearly it's not the case here. Indeed 0.2 seems to favor W1. So no independence.